# Error in Kusto function-A recognition error occurred

Tags: function, bigdata, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a source table, which receives all the fields as a space-separated string. So I am using the update policy to parse it first, do some manipulation and ingest it to the target table. But however, I am getting this error and don't know why. I have been stuck for hours, any help would really be appreciated.

```
   .create function 
   UpdateFunction()
  {
    TempTable
    | parse Record with Timestamp:datetime' 'HouseNo:string' 'Age:int'  "'Adress:string'" "'Name:string'" 'Gender:string' 'CountryCode:string 
    | extend FullName = split(Path,"?")
    | join  kind=leftouter countryTable on $left.CountryCode==$right.CountryCode
    | project "Admitted", Timestamp,House,Age,Adress,Country,tostring(FullName[0]),tostring(FullName[1])
}
```

a sample record will look like this-

- 20-12-2021 20B 7 "XYZ House, New York" "Anna Thomas" Female US

and my target table data should be like this

- Admitted,20-12-2021,20B,21, XYZ House New York, United States, Anna, Thomas

countryTable has the country mapping to the corresponding country codes.

Answer (score 2):

For next time, please include a request ID in your message. You can copy it from the web explorer using this button:

[image]

Assuming I was able to locate your requests correctly, I believe you had an extra open quotes at the end of the parse operator line, with no corresponding closing quote. I see some successful requests after that. Please reply back with a request ID if you are still experiencing the same issues.